# Custom cache key missed authentication cache. Need to re-challenge the user to login again

Tags: security, websphere-liberty, ltpa

Using liberty 18.0.0.1 set up in a collective. I have a custom TAI that creates a subject with a custom cache key. This works out of the box with WAS Classic Cell, but in my collective, when authenticated on one server, and then acessing another server ( in the same collective) a new authentication is forced.

Did some tracing and reason seems to be quite clear:

```
 [4/2/18 18:02:08:659 CEST] 00000803 id=93e3914a com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.AuthenticationException   < <init> Exit  
   com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.AuthenticationException: Custom cache key missed authentication cache. Need to re-challenge the user to login again.
```

Earlier in the trace is shows clearly that the ltpa token is processes ok, the custom key is retrieved, but

```
[4/2/18 18:02:08:659 CEST] 00000803 id=aea8ae88 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPATokenService     < recreateTokenFromBytes Exit  
  /VRnC blabla <the rest removed by me ..>
 [4/2/18 18:02:08:659 CEST] 00000803 id=         com.ibm.ws.security.token.internal.TokenManagerImpl          3 Successfully recreated token using token service com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPATokenService@aea8ae88.
```

So why is the authentication cache from server1 not visible for server2 ?

/bwa

Answer (score 0):

When you use the custom cache key, this mean there are some custom stuffs in the subject that we can not re-create this subject with the ltpa token. Liberty authentication cache does not share with other servers.

Regards,
Ut Le

Comment: I have created this RFE, if IBM implemented this, it would work, right ?
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=119066

Comment: It would be better if Liberty would continue without, as the new server might recreate the custom data, based of the loggend on Principal. This behaveiour could be configurable